# Javascript Evaluate axios const result as string

Tags: javascript, axios

I am using axios to get an element value that I need to handle it as a string.

```
const aa = await axios
  .get(`document.querySelector('h2').innerText;`)
  .then((r) => r.data.result.value);

console.log(aa);
```

then, I need to check for example if the element `aa.startsWith("somestring")`, but is not accepted, even aa is logged in the console with the expected value.

In general, how could I convert the const result from axios into a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @RobinZigmond no, so I am getting the expected value so the call is awaited. My question is more about how to cast the response into a string to do a comparison

Comment: Oh I'd missed that you were already using `await` here. In that case `aa` will already be the string that you want, so what's the problem?

Comment: oh except your axios call doesn't make sense - you're not making an HTTP request, you're just using `document.querySelector` to inspect something from the DOM of the current page. You don't need axios, or Promises, for that - you can just do `const aa = document.querySelector('h2').innerText`!

Comment: I don't understand. What you're passing to axios now isn't a URL. Do you intend to use the content of the DOM element as the request's URL?